# Remainders $\quad 1\quad 2\quad $ only

Tags: nt.number-theory

**NOTATION**:   $P(x)$   stands for the product of all primes which do not exceed real   $x$;   e.g.   $P(10)=210$.

**QUESTION**:   Given any real   $x\ge 3$,   compute or estimate the smallest natural number   $n:=n(x)\ge 3$   such the remainder of the division of   $n$   by any odd prime   $p\le x$   is   $1$ or $2$   (it may be any combination of   $1$s   and   $2$s).

In particular, improve upon my simple theorem below, and still better upon its consecutive improvements provided by the MO participants.

**THEOREM**
$$ n(x)\ > \ \left\lceil\sqrt{P(x)}\right\rceil + 1 $$

**EXAMPLEs** (small calculations):

- $n(3) = 4$
- $n(5) = 7$
- $n(7) = 16$

**REMARK (warning)**: First I talk about **all** primes (see **NOTATION**), then about **odd** primes (see **QUESTION**).

---

**PROOF of the THEOREM**

Let integer   $n\ge 3$   be such that all mentioned remainders are   $1$   or   $2$.   Let   $A$   be the product of all odd primes   $p\le x$   for which   $n=1\mod p$, and   $B$   be the same for remainder   $2$.   Thus   $A|n-1$   and   $B|n-2$,   and

$$A\cdot B\ =\ \frac{P(x)}2 $$

Furthermore,   $2|n-1$   or   $2|n-2$,   hence   $A'|n-1$   and   $B'|n-2$   for certain natural numbers such that

$$ A'\cdot B'\ =\ P(x) $$

It follows that

$$ n\ \ \ge\ \ \max(A'\ B') + 1$$

while

$$ \max(A'\ B')\ \ \ge\ \ \left\lceil\sqrt{A'\cdot B'}\right\rceil\ \ =\ \ \left\lceil\sqrt{P(x)}\right\rceil $$

This proves the required inequality:

$$ n\ \ \ge\ \ \left\lceil\sqrt{P(x)}\right\rceil + 1 $$

Comment: $n(11)=211$, I think.

Comment: @Gerry: I can see that the remainders are right hence $n(11)\le 211$. And now I should write a small program or improve my small theorem, which only assures us that $n(11)\ge 49$, which already feels awfully weak (mea culpa :-). Thank you Gerry.

Comment: To double-check Gerry's nearly-calculation one needs to verify only integers $11\cdot k+1$ and $11\cdot k+2$ in the range $49\ldots 210$, which amounts to less than $30$ candidate integers. It can be patiently computed by hand like this: $$7|56\quad 3|57\quad _7 67_4\quad _7 68_5\ \ldots$$ except that it's a little bit too embarrassing :-) (we already see that $n(11) \ge 78$, ok, that $n(11)\ge 79$, etc.).

Comment: Continuation. Since $11=1 \mod 5$ we need $k=1 \mod 5$ or $5|k$ or $k=4 \mod 5$. Is it beneath one's honor to perform the reduced amount of calculation by hand (by the brute force of one's calculating power)?

Comment: We have $n(13) = n(17) = 716$, while $\sqrt{P(17)} \approx 714$. -- Thus for $x = 17$ your inequality is pretty sharp.

Comment: How nice--thank you, @Stefan. Also, I am curious, can't help it, if you used a computer?

Comment: @Stefan: you have discovered an interesting case of primes $p<q$ such that $n(p)=n(q)$. On one hand it should not happen too often (just naive probability), and on the other hand somehow it does not surprize me (after the fact) that there are pairs of primes like this. Actually one should talk about intervals of primes (not just pairs). What would be the longest interval? How big (if any) would be three primes $p<q<r$ such that $n(p)=n(q)=n(r)$?

Comment: So far I haven't found an instance of $n(p) = n(q) = n(r)$, at least.

Comment: What's going on with 716 reminds me of the "Ruth-Aaron pair", 714 and 715; $714=2x3x7x17$, $715=5x11x13$ (and $2+3+7+17=5+11+13$, although that's not relevant here).  Also brings to mind Stormer's Theorem, about consecutive smooth numbers.

Comment: Presumably the proof of the theorem goes something like this: given $x$, we can write $P(x) = 2P_1(x)P_2(x)$ where $n(x) \equiv 1\pmod {P_1(x)}$ and  $n(x) \equiv 2\pmod {P_2(x)}$; therefore $n(x)$ exceeds the larger of $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$.

Comment: @Greg: close. After your "therefore" you lost a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ though.

Comment: So $714\times 715=P(17)$. Is there another pair of consecutive integers so that $n(n+1)=P(k)$ for some $k$? Or is this impossible?

Comment: I mean, we also have $2\times3=P(3)$, $5\times6=P(5)$, $14\times 15=P(7)$, but are there any instances with $k\ge19$?

Comment: @Yoav, this was discussed in Nelson, Penney, and Pomerance, 714 and 715, J Rec Math 7 (1974) 87-89. They went up to $k=3049$ without finding another example.

Comment: @Gary: I imagine that many people (naive and sophisticated mathematically) considered such pairs and similar after encountering Euclid infinitude of primes; one would replace Euclid's $P+1$ with $R+S$ or $R-S$, where $P$ and  $R\cdot S$ are products of a finite number of the initial primes. More generally, $R\cdot S$ can be a product of powers of such primes, with $\gcd(R\ S)=1$. These numbers are most of the time huge or $1$, and the case of $1$ makes it hard to get a new prime as small as possible.

Comment: Daniel Berend, On the roots of certain sequences of congruences, Acta Arith 67 (1994) 97-104, proves that if $P_k$ is the product of the first $k$ primes, and $x_k$ is the smallest positive solution of $x(x+1)\equiv0\pmod{P_k}$, then $x_k/P_k\to0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: In 1993-94, I got David Bailey interested in the question of whether the product of the primes up to $n$, $n\ge19$, could be a product of two consecutive integers, and he searched up to $n=23,000$. Later, Peter Montgomery took the search up to $n=50,000$. No examples were found. I don't know whether anything got published.

Comment: Also here -- http://www.primepuzzles.net/conjectures/conj_018.htm -- we have the note: "Erdös conjectured that min (X-Y)=1 for only n=1, 2, 3, 4 & 7. This has been verified recently by Chris Nash up to n=600000. As far as John knows his conjecture has never been posted before."

Comment: Are all the extra spaces (`\quad`, `\ `, `&nbsp;`) really necessary?

Comment: Nice format is important to me. I understand though "different strokes for different folks"--why, some prefer "de gustibus non est disputandum".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values $n(p)$ for primes $13 \leq p < 100$, found by computation: $n(13) = n(17) = 716$,
$n(19) = 62987$,
$n(23) = 367082$, $n(29) = 728366$, $n(31) = 64822396$, $n(37) = 1306238012$,
$n(41) = 11182598506$, $n(43) = 715041747422$, $n(47) = 51913478860882$,
$n(53) = 454746157008782$, $n(59) = 9314160363311806$, $n(61) = n(67) = 261062105979210901$,
$n(71) = 696537082207206753592$, $n(73) = 54097844397380813592487$,
$n(79) = 286495021083846822067822$, $n(83) = 80126789479717708423427656$,
$n(89) = 1560127578864999430859224576$, $n(97) = 161426380685234430031618378951$.

**Edit:** For completeness -- the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) code for computing these values
is as follows:

```
n := function ( x )

  local  primes, remainders, solutions;

  primes     := Filtered([3..x],IsPrime);
  remainders := Tuples([1,2],Length(primes));
  solutions  := List(remainders,rem->ChineseRem(primes,rem));
  return Minimum(Difference(solutions,[1,2]));
end;
```

Comment: Let $p<q$ be consecutive odd primes. If $$\frac{n(q)}{n(p)}<\sqrt q$$ then--by definition--the jump is low; otherwise the jump is high (the inequality is always sharp). It seemed to me that low/high depends (but not consistently) on the $\mod 4$ class of $q$. When $q=3\mod 4$ then the jump is either extra low or extra high depending on the parity of the number of primes $s < q$ which are congruent to $3\mod 4$. Your, @Stefan, list seems to confirm this conjecture. There should be also other considerations which occasionally mess up this tendency; it still should be the most common tendency.

Comment: Here are the ratios $[n(p)-1][n(p)-2]/P(p)$ (necessarily integers) for $p=3,5,\ldots,97$: 1, 1, 1, 19, 17, 1, 409, 604, 82, 20951, 229931, 411012, 39080794, 
4382914408, 6345486566, 45119290746, 581075656330, 8672770990, 
869561574799171, 71853663603175593, 25509154378676494, 
24040267482771436703, 102403319155457392955, 11302410854347731819765

Comment: The numbers $n(p)-2$ are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A118478 and the ratios are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A215021 but neither page has anything about rate of growth.

Comment: @Gerry, our own MO Stefan Kohl got further than OEIS! Good reflex and association, Gerry, great links--thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Speculatively, as for now, we could assume that the smallest difference between $n(x)$ and  $\sqrt{P(x)}$ is for $x=17$ (see Stefan's comment). 
Thus, a natural improvement to your theorem (conjecture?) could be the following:
$$n(x)\geq P(x)^{a}$$
Where 
$a=\log_p716$ and $p=510510$, so
$ a\approx 0.50016$

Or simpler:
$$ n(x)\ > \ \sqrt{P(x)}+1$$

Comment: your first inequality is an interesting conjecture. The second one I had from the beginning, and just somehow neglected to type it in full (just psychology or funny laziness). Yes, it's a theorem, not just a conjecture. Indeed, actual inequality is $$n(x)\ge\left\lceil\sqrt{P(x)}\right\rceil+1$$ Its proof is very simple.

Comment: Thus, referring to your original question, as we know a case for $x=17$ we can conclude that, in general, the inequality $$n(x)\ge\left\lceil\sqrt{P(x)}\right\rceil+1$$
cannot be improved.

Comment: Thank you, @Waldemar, that's pleasing. To celebrate it I'll add the proof of my small theorem to my "Question". On the other hand one still can strive at getting sharper results, e.g. for $x > M$ (say, for $x \ge 19 :-) or other forms.

Comment: It could also be of interest to find an upper bound for $n(x)$ which would be an improvement over the following one: $$n(x)\leq \frac{P(x)}{2}+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let me make a tiny-microscopic improvement. Let   $n := n(x)$.   Then

$$ P(x)\ |\ (n-1)\cdot(n-2)\ =\ \left(n-\frac 32\right)^2 - \frac 14$$

It follows that:

**THEOREM**

$$ n(x)\quad \ge\quad \left\lceil\sqrt{P(x)+\frac 14}\ +\ \frac 32\right\rceil $$